# CSquotes package displays a [?] at end of quote

Tags: csquotes

I have this babel template. The problem is that the csquotes package produces a '[?]' at the end. How can I remove it please?

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{report}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[english, provide=*, bidi=basic, layout=counters.tabular]{babel}
\babelprovide{arabic}
\babelfont[arabic]{rm}{Traditional Arabic}
\babelfont{rm}[Renderer=Harfbuzz]{Times New Roman}

\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Temp}

\begin{displaycquote}{bibid}
«This is a temporary chapter. Number 256.»
\end{displaycquote}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `displaycquote` environment includes a `\cite` to the entry key given in the first mandatory argument. So your display quote essentially automatically does `\cite{bibid}`. If you don't have a citation setup, where `bibid` is a valid key, you get the output for a missing citation.

If you don't want the citation here, use `displayquote` (without the `c`) without a mandatory argument for an entry key.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{report}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[english, provide=*, bidi=basic, layout=counters.tabular]{babel}
\babelprovide{arabic}
\babelfont[arabic]{rm}{Traditional Arabic}
\babelfont{rm}[Renderer=Harfbuzz]{Times New Roman}

\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Temp}

\begin{displayquote}
«This is a temporary chapter. Number 256.»
\end{displayquote}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

---

Note that you can make `csquotes` generate quotation marks in `displayquote` automatically. You won't have to type them yourself.

You could use the approach from [How to force csquotes to show the quotations marks in block quotes?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/101809/35864)

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{report}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[english, provide=*, bidi=basic, layout=counters.tabular]{babel}
\babelprovide{arabic}
\babelfont[arabic]{rm}{Traditional Arabic}
\babelfont{rm}[Renderer=Harfbuzz]{Times New Roman}

\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\renewcommand{\mkblockquote}[4]{\openautoquote#1\closeautoquote#2#4#3}
\renewcommand{\mkbegdispquote}[2]{\openautoquote}
\renewcommand{\mkenddispquote}[2]{\closeautoquote#1#2}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Temp}

\begin{displayquote}
This is a temporary chapter. Number 256.
\end{displayquote}

\chapter{Other}

\kant[1]

\noindent\hrulefill

\blockquote{%
% extract from \kant[2]%
Let us suppose that the noumena have nothing to do with necessity,
since knowledge of the Categories is \enquote{\textbf{a posteriori}}.
Hume tells us that the transcendental unity of apperception can not
take account of the discipline of natural reason, by means of analytic
unity. As is proven in the ontological manuals, it is obvious that the
transcendental unity of apperception proves the validity of the
Antinomies.%
}

\noindent\hrulefill

\begin{displayquote}
% extract from \kant[3]%
As is shown in the writings of Aristotle, the things in themselves
(and it remains a mystery why this is the case) are a representation
of time. Our concepts have lying before them the paralogisms of
natural reason, but our \enquote{\textbf{a posteriori}} concepts have
lying before them the practical employment of our experience.
\end{displayquote}

\end{document}
```

With `english` this will give double quotes and not guillemets as in your example, though. (This could be changed.)

Comment: Thanks very much!

Comment: Is it possible to let the quotes signs appear bigger?

Comment: @ellat Well the size you get is normal for the text size. If you want comically large quotation marks, you may want to look into https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16964/35864 and linked questions.